# Blazor web application hosted on a remote server using IIS. Unable to access HTTP, while HTTPS is fine (besides the Not secure flag))

Tags: http, https, blazor, web-hosting

I have a Blazor server-side web application hosted on a remote server using IIS.

I cannot access it with `http://urlofwebsite.com`, while `https://urlofwebsite.com` is fine (besides the not secure flag)).

Why is it accessible using `https` but not `http`? And can I update it to be accessible with both?

Tried using Port 80 for http, and 443 for https.
Using * as IP address for both http and https in Sitebindings ISS.

Answer (score 0):

With the information provided in the question at the time of this answer, I would suspect that your Blazor app is configured to to this:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

or something similar is happening somewhere else (e.g. URL re-write rule in IIS)